# Show matrix values around matched elements

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I have created a matrix and would like to find all the places where there is a "1", then change all 4 adjacent cells to a character or number, say a full stop (".") or number 2.

I can obtain the 4 arrays of the positions I want, i.e the adjacent cells to the location of the "1"s. However I am not sure how to return them and then change them without using an extremely long loop of each of the 4 arrays one row at a time.

e.g. I have a matrix

```
Y<-matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1),byrow=TRUE,ncol=4)
Y
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1    0
[3,]    1    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    1    1
```

And I want to end up with:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    2    0
[2,]    2    2    1    2
[3,]    1    2    1    2
[4,]    2    2    1    1
```

So to get all the locations where I would like to place the 2s I do:

```
Y1<-which(Y==1,arr.ind=TRUE)
a1<-t(rbind(Y1[,1][Y1[,1]-1>0]-1,Y1[,2][Y1[,1]-1>0]))
a2<-t(rbind(Y1[,1][Y1[,1]+1<=R]+1,Y1[,2][Y1[,1]+1<=R]))
b1<-t(rbind(Y1[,1][Y1[,2]-1>0],Y1[,2][Y1[,2]-1>0]-1))
b2<-t(rbind(Y1[,1][Y1[,2]+1<=C],Y1[,2][Y1[,2]+1<=C]+1))

> Y1
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   3   1
[3,]   2   3
[4,]   3   3
[5,]   4   3
[6,]   4   4
```

So for example I want all the indexes (row and columns) which are one index below all the 1s:

```
> a1
      row  col
[1,]    2    1
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    2    3
[4,]    3    3
[5,]    3    4
```

How can I find all these positions in the matrix Y and replace whatever is there with another value but keep all the 1s?

Comment: I think it boils down to this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46933235/322912

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I would have to go through all the columns or rows 1 by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Pretty simple just use the which function and add/subtract n for values directly n places above/below desired points. And add/subtract n + nrow for values n places left/right of desired points.
e.g.

```
> M<-matrix(c(2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),nrow=6,ncol=7)
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
[2,]    2    2    2    1    2    2    2
[3,]    2    2    2    2    1    2    2
[4,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
[5,]    1    1    2    2    2    2    2
[6,]    1    1    2    2    2    2    2

l<-length(which(M==1))

if(l>0){
    l1<-which(M==1)-nrow(M); l1<-l1[l1>0]
    r1<-which(M==1)+nrow(M); r1<-r1[r1<=prod(dim(M))]
    u1<-which(M==1)[which(M==1)%%nrow(M)!=1]-1
    d1<-which(M==1)[which(M==1)%%nrow(M)!=0]+1

    M[l1][which(M[l1]!=1)]<-"."
    M[r1][which(M[r1]!=1)]<-"."
    M[u1][which(M[u1]!=1)]<-"."
    M[d1][which(M[d1]!=1)]<-"."
  }
M<-replace(M,which(M==1,arr.ind=TRUE),".")

> M
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,] "2"  "2"  "2"  "."  "2"  "2"  "2" 
[2,] "2"  "2"  "."  "."  "."  "2"  "2" 
[3,] "2"  "2"  "2"  "."  "."  "."  "2" 
[4,] "."  "."  "2"  "2"  "."  "2"  "2" 
[5,] "."  "."  "."  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2" 
[6,] "."  "."  "."  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"
```